# Switch back to App when key is pressed [MAUI/C#]

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I want to switch back to my app if a key is pressed. My app provide the possebility to switch to Googlemaps for navigation. I want the switch back to my app if the VolumeUp Button is pressed.

under Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs
I have the posibility to listen to the key commands. But this is only working if my App is already in the active state.

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
            {
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not going to happen. Those key events you are trying to use require focus, and obviously your activity is not. You should research AccessibilityService or InputMethod. Perhaps even try some dark magic with the Audio Manager. Btw, back button that closes Google maps will bring your app back to focus. I do not know why you need this at first place.

Comment: Totally agreed with the comment above, This is impossible

Comment: Pressing the volume button on the phone to jump to another app is not supported. You can try setting relevant events for Google Maps to jump to the app.